# Angular 11 : Filter List of Objects with List of Objects via Pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, list, filter, pipe

I have a FormControl and the top of the page where I can select objects (which I call 'Tags') in order to filter a List of other objects underneath it

For example , I would select two object like so :

```
[
    {
        "id": "4",
        "index": 4,
        "isActive": false,
        "picture": "https://via.placeholder.com/20x20",
        "name": "Interest 4"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "index": 5,
        "isActive": false,
        "picture": "https://via.placeholder.com/20x20",
        "name": "Interest 5"
    }
]
```

And then attempt to filter it against my list (which I call 'Posts') against the post.postTags property.

```
{
    "id": "RMjImD7Iy327rZOIBDfm",
    "createdDate": "07/17/2021 20:31:02",
    "posterId": "GI2Xs9YDV2UOh8M1J6zISvDt7wb2",
    "posterName": "example@email.com",
    "title": "New post with example email",
    "bodyText": "The quick, brown fox jumps over a lazy dog. DJs flock by when MTV ax quiz prog. Junk MTV quiz graced by fox whelps. Bawds jog, flick quartz, vex nymphs. Waltz, bad nymph, for quick jigs vex! Fox nymphs grab quick-jived waltz. Brick quiz whangs jumpy veldt fox. Bright vixens jump; dozy fowl quack. Quick wafting zephyrs vex bold Jim. Quick zephyrs blow, vexing daft Jim. Sex-charged fop blew my junk TV quiz. How quickly daft jumping zebras vex. Two driven jocks help fax my big quiz. Quick, Baz, get my woven flax jodhpurs! \"Now fax quiz Jack!\" my brave ghost pled.",
    "posterPicture": "../../../../../assets/images/user/wip-avatar.png",
    "postTags": [
        {
            "id": "4",
            "index": 4,
            "isActive": false,
            "picture": "https://via.placeholder.com/20x20",
            "name": "Interest 4"
        },
        {
            "picture": "https://via.placeholder.com/20x20",
            "id": "7",
            "name": "Interest 7",
            "isActive": false,
            "index": 7
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Interest 2",
            "isActive": false,
            "index": 2,
            "picture": "https://via.placeholder.com/20x20"
        }
    ]
}
```

Screenshot of list console.log
[image: List]

My current filterPipe looks like this :
[image: Pipe]

but so far unable to figure the correct logic out.
I want the logic to be able to:

- Filter any posts which possess any (one or more) of the selected tags in the Posts postTags field.
- Return original list if no tags are selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return your original array if there is not tag is selected, you can use a ternary operator like so.

```js
return term.length > 0 ? otherStuffHere : items
```

In the case if either `otherStuffHere` or `items` can be null or undefined you can make this better by adding some nullish coalescing, returning a default value if needed.

```js
return (term.length > 0 ? otherStuffHere : items) ?? []
```

which basically means : if `(term ? otherStuffHere : items)` is null or undefined, use `[]` instead. ([check this out](https://twitter.com/thelittlestdev/status/1415213119731814401))
This is only if you use angular 12 or greater. otherwise, use `||` instead of `??`.

So there you have the answer to the second part of your question (`Return original list if no tags are selected.`)

---

As for the first part of your question, things get more interesting.

What you basically want is to check if at least one condition is true (at least one tag of the item is in the tag list) for an item to be in your filtered list.

Javascript implements the `some()` method in the array prototype doing just what you want. [docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

In your case, this is what the filter method should look like :

```js
items.filter(item => 
    item.postTag.some(pTag => term.some(t => t.id === pTag.id))
);
```

Another way to do it would be like this

```js
items.filter(item => 
    item.postTag.some(pTag => term.map(t => t.id).include(pTag.id))
);
```

and you could keep `term.map(t => t.id)` in a variable changing the second code exmaple to this :

```js
const termIds = term.map(t => t.id);

items.filter(item => 
    item.postTag.some(pTag => termIds.include(pTag.id))
);
```

Please note, and this is very important. My arrow functions do not inclue a return, as I do not use curly brackets. [Some reading here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). This is also one issue you had in your code.

```js
items.filter(item => {
    item.postTags.filter(tag => tag === term);
});
```

would have always returned `[]`, an empty array.

Another problem in your code is the `tag === term`, which compares the references of the objects, and not their values. This is why I compare the items on their id.

---

So as a final answer to your question, your transofrm method (if I am correct) should look like this :

```js
transform(items: any[], term: any[]): any[] {
    return (term.length > 0 ?
        items.filter(item => 
            item.postTag.some(pTag => term.map(t => t.id).include(pTag.id))
        ) :
        items ) ?? [];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Paul for your swift reponse. Your solutions works :)